# Ruby/Sinatra Ajax-heavy driven app How-Tos

Tags: ruby, ajax, extjs, sinatra

I am planning to create a single page, where a user can load his data and manipulate it. It should have a very desktop-like feel (slick driven by ajax).
I evaluated some javascript widget frameworks and decided to try out ExtJS (although any other recommendations would be welcome as long as it supports some sort of a Grid/Table/Cell element this is absolutely a must).

The thing is, that I have never done anything like this before. Most of the time, when I build regular web pages it's just a handful of jQuery calls to load html, send some data, hide/show elements, and I have to say that this feels very clunky and I believe such approach wouldn't yield the best results if I was to keep things this way.

I would really like to see some examples how people build such pages, a repository with an app would be great. I am very interested to see how to communicate between the server/client widgets as seemless as possible. Any pointers appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout these sites :

[qWikiOffice](http://www.qwikioffice.com/desktop-demo/login.html)  : Open source ExtJS based desktop application

[iDuple](http://iduple.com)  : A full fledged ExtJS based Desktop application

[Cloudo](http://cloudo.com/)  : Javascript/XML based application

Answer (score 4):

i suggest you use ExtJs (mybe because i'm an Extjs fan hehe :) )

1. `It should have a very desktop-like feel` yes,extjs can do it... take look [this](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/desktop/desktop.html)
2. `Most of the time, when I build regular web pages it's just a handful of jQuery`, with extjs.. you can mix it with JQuery, prototype, and Yui too.. (at least in version 3.3.x)
3. `I would really like to see some examples`.. [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/) you are
4. `how to communicate between the server/client widgets as seemless as possible`, how extjs work is they use [json](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and [ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX). so transfer data is more lighter. extjs can work with almost any programming language (if it can produce json of course).

just an advice, now extjs have been issued a 4.0 beta 3.. and of course with big change and more powerfull. so i suggest you try learning newer version. even it's just a beta version.. one of the big change is the implementation of MVC concept and data model.. goodluck with your project...

Answer (score 3):

You should look into [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/). Its an amazing javascript framework from **DocumentCloud** which provides you with Models, Views and Collections which can be easily mapped to any MVC on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

[Sproutcore](http://sproutcore.com) and [Cappuccino](http://cappuccino.org) are a couple of other interesting frameworks.